# I declared the same function with same output

Tags: c, terminal, cs50

Programming on C, weirdly I declare void edges(...) output as void and do the same thing below int main(void) however, I get an error message that I'm declaring a different output. I was wondering what is wrong with this?

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

typedef struct{
    int  rgbtBlue;
    int  rgbtGreen;
    int  rgbtRed;
}
RGBTRIPLE;

int make_image_array(int);
void edges(int, int, RGBTRIPLE);

int main(void){
    edges(height, width, image[height][width]);
}



void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{}
```

[image: 1]

The error message on terminal which says conflicting types for the function edges???

Comment: `void edges(int, int, RGBTRIPLE);` is not `void edges(int, int, (*RGBTRIPLE)[width]);` Since you are using a VLA, `void edges(int a, int b, RGBTRIPLE[a][b]);` will work. With your current code shown, there is no need to link against `-lcs50`, `-lcrypt` or `-lm` -- add them when you use something that requires them.

Comment: Your function declaration takes two integers and one RGBTRIPLE, while your definition takes two integers and a 2D *array* of RGBTRIPLE values. These declarations specify different types and as such, are clearly conflicting.

Answer (score 2):

The short version of the story is -- your compiler is right...

If you look at your prototype:

```
void edges(int, int, RGBTRIPLE);
```

It takes three parameters, an `int`, `int`, and `anonymous struct RGBTRIPLE`. However, when you *define* the function, you define a 2D array of `RGBTRIPLE`, e.g.

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{}
```

See the difference? A single `RGBTRIPLE` in the prototype and `RGBTRIPLE[height][width]` in the definition.

The simplest way to fix your prototype is to provide named variables that can be used as the required dimensions for your 2D VLA, e.g.

```
void edges(int a, int b, RGBTRIPLE[a][b]);
```

Even better, do away with the prototype altogether and simply define `edges` above `main()` -- that way you eliminate the chance of any mismatch.